# Points array visualization in 3d

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, graph, 3d

I need to show points array in three-dimensional coordinate system. Which component or library should I use for it(Winforms/WPF)?

Comment: WPF is "best" any 2d/3d visual presentation over winforms.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial for Direct3D in C#, it's for winforms: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms920768.aspx. I don't think it matters whether you use winforms or wpf, the trick is to get your videocard do you drawing and that bypasses wpf.